# Android Socket client unable to send and receive messages

Tags: android, python, sockets, twisted

I want to send and receive messages from my socket server which is created in python on windows with the help of twisted API. My client is going to be my android phone through I am going send my string messages. Here is my code. can someone please help out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
//TextView textView;
Button sendButton;
Button connect;
EditText message;
OutputStream outputStream;
InputStream inputStream;
Socket socket;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            connect.setText("Disconnect");
            AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask() {
                @Override
                protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)
                {
                    try {
                         socket = new Socket("192.168.100.106",8888);
                        try {
                            outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                            inputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                            connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {

                                    try {
                                        socket.close();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            sendButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view)
                                {
                                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
                                    String mes = message.getText().toString();
                                    out.print(mes);
                                }
                            });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            asyncTask.execute();
        }
    });

}
}
```

And here is my socket server script coded in python with the help of twisted API.

```
    from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
class DataTransfer(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
            #self.transport.write("""connected""")
            self.factory.clients.append(self)
            print "clients are ", self.factory.clients
            self.username = ""
            self.password = ""
            self.auth = False
            self.ipaddress = self.transport.getPeer()
            print self.ipaddress

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
        print reason

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print data
        a = data.split(':')
        if len(a) > 1:
                    command = a[0]
                    content = a[1]

                    msg = ""

                    self.message(msg)

    def message(self, message):
            self.transport.write(message + '\n')

factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = DataTransfer
factory.clients = []

reactor.listenTCP(8888, factory)
print "Server started"
reactor.run()
```

Presently I am able to communicate (ie. connect and disconnect with the server.) but its just that I am not able to send and receive messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);` directly use the outputStream and it should work. :)